# How to upgrade a project to C# 6

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I read that the C# 6 could allow new things like this :

```
if (decimal.TryParse(txtPrice.Txt, out decimal price)) 
    product.Price = price;
```

instead of this :

```
decimal price; 
if (decimal.TryParse(txtPrice.Txt, out price)) 
    product.Price = price;
```

I would like to use it like many other features (new operator `?.`, etc..) of the C# 6 in my project.
I'm currently working on a webform project but when I'm writing this :

```
Int32.TryParse(newValue.ToString().Trim(), out int intNumber)
```

or

```
Int32.TryParse(newValue.ToString().Trim(), out Int32 intNumber)
```

The compiler doesn't build and it says me that expression doesn't work.

Do you know how could I upgrade my project to use C# 6 features please ?

Comment: Does your compiler *have* C# 6.0?  You can't use new features of a language unless the compiler understands the new features.

Comment: I'm also using TFS standalone version. Should I upgrade this too ? Will it upgrade itself automatically ?

Answer (score 5):

Just install the Roslyn [End User Preview](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394641), assuming you are using VS2013. Note that link is not working for me currently (spinning indefinitely), but: this is the link from the Rosyln [codeplex page](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/)

Edit: Here's the actual link: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=52793

Comment: I just create my account on connect.microsoft.com. But when I click on your link the page show me an error. I can't access to the content (probably due to my account permission)

Comment: @wytes did you accept the license terms? Also: make sure you use the "download single file" link (bottom-right in the table)